# Bootstrap calendar get currently showing events

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I'm currently working on this project where I need to show events in a calendar and in tiles.

Everything from this calendar is working, but I wonder if there is any way to get the elements that are currently shown.
What I mean is: you select a week, in this week are 3 events. Can I get these 3 events? Is there an action for this like $("#startdate").val()?

I can then use those objects to create the tiles.
Or do you guys have any other suggestions on how to deal with this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Arno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this article and needs the answer, the function

```
calendar.options.events
```

returns an array that contains the event objects.